# How to filter a JOIN on *all* items of a given list (filter articles with all given tags for example)

Tags: mysql, join

I have this use case which seems quite usual but I don't find any efficient and obvious solution.

I have an `article` table, a `tag` table and a intermediate `article_tag` table (each article can have multiple tags, and each tag can be linked to multiple articles).

Given a list of tag ids `1, 2, 3`, I want to retrieve articles that have *all* these tags at the same time.

I easily managed to retrieve articles that have *at least* one tag in this list:

```
SELECT * FROM article a
JOIN article_tag at ON at.article_id = a.id AND at.tag_id IN (1, 2, 3)
```

This query can return articles with only 1 tag (id 2 for example). But this is *not* what I want. I want *only* the articles with the 3 exact tags 1, 2 and 3.

How to do it in an efficient way? There are quite a lot of articles, I do care about performances.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO the best way to ensure it is by using EXISTS to check one by one every condition:

```
select a.*
from   __articles a
where  exists (select 1 from __articles_tags where artid = a.artid and tagid = 1)
and    exists (select 1 from __articles_tags where artid = a.artid and tagid = 2)
and    exists (select 1 from __articles_tags where artid = a.artid and tagid = 3);
```

Bu depending on your table schema, you could use GROUP BY and COUNT to select which articles have the desired tags.

```
select   artid
from     articles_tags
where    tagid in (1,2,3)
group by artid
having   count(*) = 3
```

Then use the result list to fetch articles records.

```
select  *
from    articles
where   artid in (select   artid
                  from     articles_tags
                  where    tagid in (1,2,3)
                  group by artid
                  having   count(*) = 3);
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/LOB71207

Comment: Note that the first step above (counting the articles that have 3 tags) assumes that the `article_tags` table has one and only one record for each tag on each article. If the combination of artid and tagid in `article_tags` isn't unique, you could get false positives in this step. You can work around this by counting of times each tag appears (`SUM(CASE WHEN tagid = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`, etc.) or by pulling DISTINCT artid, tagid into a temp table, and proceeding from there. Also, if `article_tags` doesn't have a reason to have multiple entries with those column values, try to clear out dupes.

Comment: @RDFozz There is no table schema and no sample data, I've just added another solution using EXISTS for three articles-tags just to take care of duplicate data.

Comment: completely understood. Just thought it might be worth noting, in case someone inexperienced might have tried using option 1 and not have recognized the problem. If it wasn't clear, I would prefer to assume the table was nice and clean - I've just run into similar cases where it wasn't. And, yes, the `EXISTS` absolutely avoids the problem to begin with!

Comment: @RDFozz I've just changeg the order. May be it's more clear.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! Sorry I haven't mentionned: yes the combination of article_id and tag_id in `article_tags` is unique. One other think I'd like to mention as well is that I have a very restrictive condition on the article in the main query (`SELECT * FROM article a WHERE a.col = 'very restrictive value'`). Having this in mind, which way do you think has the best performances? I am afraid the subquery would return a lot of rows (a lot of articles have the same combination of tags, but only a few respect my restrictive condition). I'm not sure if it has a real impact or not. Thanks!

Comment: I think the second one has better performance due it generates a subset of aticles_tags table, and use it once.

Answer (score 0):

Another way..

```
select   artid, GROUP_CONCAT(tag_id ORDER BY tagid) AS tags
    from     articles_tags
    where    tagid in (1,2,3)
    group by artid
    having   tags = "1,2,3";
```

[*Tips*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table) on an optimal many:many mapping table